# EclipseLink: Not appending TENANT_ID to WHERE clause of query for entityManager.merge(entity) operation

Tags: eclipselink

I am using EclipseLink and Spring Data JPA for single table multi-tenancy requirement.

My problem is TENANT_ID is not appended for UPDATE operation.

Spring Data JPA internally delegate this call to `entityManager.merge(entity)` but the problem is this call is not appending TENANT_ID to WHERE clause.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
What I want : UPDATE USER SET firstName = ?, lastName = ? WHERE userName = ? and TENANT_ID =?
```

What I get : UPDATE USER SET firstName = ?, lastName = ? WHERE userName = ?.

So, this is a problem as there may be user with same **userName** for more than one tenant in a single table.

```
Why TENANT_ID is not being appended fore em.merge(entity) operation?
The same case for em.remove()
```

If it is not than , please suggest any solution for this.

Comment: This seems a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385976/eclipselink-entitymanager-merge-why-tenant-id-not-added-runtime-for-update and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370227/eclipselinkspringdatajpa-single-table-multitenancy-tenant-id-is-not-added-to-w  Why not include everything in one question since they are the same problem?

Comment: I post it earlier than the question you are saying, but at the time of posting this one, I was not aware of EclipseLink's documentation portion of the question you are saying. BTW, I will merge all these in one