# EclipseLink : EntityManager.merge() : Why TENANT_ID not added runtime for UPDATE operation?

Tags: eclipselink

I have gone through EclipseLink Single Table Multi-Tenancy feature spec.

BELOW is some portion by reading, I am little bit surprised.

Task 4: Perform Operations and Queries

```
The tenant discriminator column is used at runtime through entity manager operations and querying. The tenant discriminator column and value are supported through the following entity manager operations:

    persist()

    find()

    refresh()

The tenant discriminator column and value are supported through the following queries:

    Named queries

    Update all

    Delete all
```

Why TENANT_ID is not used at runtime for below operations.

```
merge()
delete()
```

Why It is not needed for below operations? I need it because when updating any record , I need to append TENANT_ID in WHERE clause of UPDATE query.
Because, In a single table multi-tenancy, there will be users with same user for more than one tenant and I need TENANT_ID to update only specific tenant record.

Please help me in this, as I am stuck only in merge() operation.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same symptoms and the answer for us was to add `primaryKey=true` to the tenant discriminator annotation to indicate that the tenant_id must be included as a part of the primary key used in delete and merge operations:

```
@Multitenant
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name = "tenant_id", contextProperty = "tenant_id", primaryKey=true)
```